# How to build a subquery inside a query in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
select * from tblproducts where " . $where . " order by $sort $order limit $offset,$rows
```

The above query works fine and extracts all records from **tblproducts**.

I have another table **tblsellers.**

The both tables are linked via **foreign key 'sellerid'**

How could I modify the above query so that I can extract **sellerurl** field from tblsellers based on foreign key sellerid?

Comment: using joins will be your best bet here since you have a foreign key relation between the respective tables.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [JOIN](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/):

```
SELECT
  tblproducts.*, tblsellers.sellerurl
FROM
  tblproducts INNER JOIN tblsellers
  ON tblproducts.sellerid = tblsellers.sellerid
WHERE
  ...
ORDER BY
  ...
LIMIT ...,...
```

This will return all products that have a seller. If you want to return all products you can use a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You can join two tables based on the foreign key and select the columnns you want from both tables

```
Select p.*,s.* from tblproducts p inner join tblsellers s on p.sellerid = s.id
where  $where
```

If you want to use a subquery you can use

```
Seleect sellerurl 
from tblsellers where id = (select sellerid from tblproducts where $where )
```

Comment: better not use old join semantics ... use a proper JOIN statement instead (as shown by the other answer)

Comment: @rene Thank you! is it deprecated? I really don't know why it is not recommended!

Comment: Yes, since 2002 ... http://www.kingtraining.com/confdownloads/downloads/Oracle9iJoin_paper.pdf